# How do you set the starting point in PYplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matplotlib, graph

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16], "ro")
plt.plot(x)
plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])
plt.show()
```

This code should work but it doesn't.

Comment: Why does this not work? What do you expect it to do, and what does it actually do?

Answer (score 1):

It would have worked if you had `unpacked` `x`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16], "ro")
plt.plot(*x)
plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Difference between `plot(x)` and `plot(*x)` is:

```
plot(x) -> plot(([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16], "ro")) # only one argument passed, a tuple
plot(*x) -> plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16], "ro") # three arguments passed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, was trying to figure out for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
plt.plot(*x)
```

Or use tuple unpacking.

```
x,y,s= ([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16], "ro")
plt.plot(x,y,s)
```